# RE :How can we execute a shell script file from my Android Application

Tags: android, shell

I am trying to write an android application that runs a shell commands, or a shell script if that is preferable, and displays the output... can anyone give me in the right direction?

**My code is as follows:**

```
void execCommandLine()
    {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = null;
        OutputStreamWriter osw = null;

        try
        {

            String[] str={"/system/bin/sh","/data/shTest.sh"};              
                 System.out.println("EXEC STRING");
                 proc = runtime.exec(str);
               osw = new OutputStreamWriter(proc.getOutputStream());
            //osw.write(command);
            osw.flush();
            osw.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
              Log.e("erre","ioexception");          
            //Log.e("execCommandLine()", "Command resulted in an IO Exception: " + command);
            return;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (osw != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    osw.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e){}
            }
        }

        try 
        {
            proc.waitFor();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e){}

        if (proc.exitValue() != 0)
        {
            Log.e("erre","interruotexception");         
            //Log.e("execCommandLine()", "Command returned error: " + command + "\n  Exit code: " + proc.exitValue());
        }
    }
     // **************************************
```

Code is running successfully but I am not getting any output in adb shell logcat 
would anyone tell me if this script is executed successfully how to get this output 
in Adb shell.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into `GScript`. It is quite flexible.